# Get value "onchange"

Tags: javascript, html

How do I access the value of the selected option in an onchange handler for a select element?

For example, what would I replace `this.value` with in the below code?

```
    <select id = "Div" name="Div" onchange="new SmartyAjax.update('div_update', 'Div/(this.value)', '','muwap=true','' );">
  <option value="0">Main Div</option>
  <option value="1">Extra Div 1</option>
  <option value="2">Extra Div 2</option>
  <option value="3">Extra Div 3</option>
  <option value="4">Extra Div 4</option>
  <option value="5">Extra Div 5</option>
  <option value="6">Extra Div 6</option>
  <option value="7">Extra Div 7</option>
  <option value="8">Extra Div 8</option>
  <option value="9">Extra Div 9</option>
  <option value="10">Extra Div 10</option>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: when i change <select> i want to get <option value> where is (this.value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer is more complex than it needs to be:

```html
<select onchange="alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
  <option value="0" selected>Main Div</option>
  <option value="1">Extra Div 1</option>
  <option value="2">Extra Div 2</option>
  <option value="3">Extra Div 3</option>
  <option value="4">Extra Div 4</option>
  <option value="5">Extra Div 5</option>
  <option value="6">Extra Div 6</option>
  <option value="7">Extra Div 7</option>
  <option value="8">Extra Div 8</option>
  <option value="9">Extra Div 9</option>
  <option value="10">Extra Div 10</option>
 </select>
```

In the `onchange` handler, `this` is the select element and so `this.options[this.selectedIndex]` gives you the selected option, and `.value` accesses the value attribute.

Comment: Thank you, but, how i can make this?

<select id = "div" name="div" onchange="new SmartyAjax.update('div_update', 'this.options[this.selectedIndex].value', '','','' );">

Comment: @MeTa the problem is you're passing it as a string, you're passing the literal string, 'this.options ....' -- you don't want the *text* you want the expression, so get rid of the single quotes around it, like:

`<select id = "div" name="div" onchange="new SmartyAjax.update('div_update', this.options[this.selectedIndex].value, '','','' );">`

Comment: yes, is work only with this.oprions[].value but, how i can make this? 
`new SmartyAjax.update('div_update', 'Div/'this.options[this.selectedIndex].value, '','','' );`.

Comment: I made it! :)

`onchange="new SmartyAjax.update('div_update','Div/'+this.options[this.selectedIndex].value, '','muwap=true','' );`

Thank you very much Doug!

Answer (score 1):

To get the value of the selected option you need to first get the the **SELECT** element by it's ID like this:

```
var select = document.getElementById("Div");
```

Then you need to actually get the value of the **OPTION** that is currently selected like so:

`var currentValue = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;`

Or if you want to retrieve the option's text instead of it's value you can just do the following:

`var currentOptionText = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;`

So if you wanted to get the value on change you would need to create a function that contained the above code and run that function **ONCHANGE** like this:

```js
function getOptValue() {
  var select = document.getElementById("Div");
  var optionValue = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  
  //do whatever you'd like with the value here
  alert(optionValue); //with this alert we can check if the value is actually retrieved
 }
```

```html
<select id = "Div" name="Div" onchange="getOptValue();">
  <option value="0" selected>Main Div</option>
  <option value="1">Extra Div 1</option>
  <option value="2">Extra Div 2</option>
  <option value="3">Extra Div 3</option>
  <option value="4">Extra Div 4</option>
  <option value="5">Extra Div 5</option>
  <option value="6">Extra Div 6</option>
  <option value="7">Extra Div 7</option>
  <option value="8">Extra Div 8</option>
  <option value="9">Extra Div 9</option>
  <option value="10">Extra Div 10</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: **UPDATED**
With code example.